# Background image inside contact form 7 textarea

Tags: css, wordpress, background-image, contact-form

I am trying to add a background image inside a textarea on a contact form. The problem is that as soon as browser is resized, the image is cut off meaning it doesn't fit the textarea box perfectly. I would like the textarea to display the whole image and resize it with resizing the browser. Not sure if there is a solution to this at all.

here is my code

```
#contactfooter {
    background-color: rgba(76, 73, 73, 0.44);
    color: rgb(183, 181, 181);
    border: 1px solid #676363;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

textarea#contactfooter {
background-color: rgba(76, 73, 73, 0.44);
background: url(https://psycheseminars.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/textback.jpg);
}
```

Here is the page https://psycheseminars.com/downloads/spirit-salt-lake-city/
The contact form is in the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try below code.

```
textarea#contactfooter {
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I have done it many times but because I don't have enough authority, it does not count my vote yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the whole image to display by setting the background-size property of the textarea to contain, but then the image will not cover the whole background because of it's dimensions, and the rest of the space will fill with a repeat unless you set background-repeat to no-repeat.  However, I think the repeat would be more desirable in this case... anyways you can play with it yourself but to answer your specific question of how to get the whole image to display just change your css for the textarea to this:

```
textarea#contactfooter {
    background-color: rgba(76, 73, 73, 0.44);
    background: url(https://psycheseminars.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/textback.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Also, you could also set the background-position to center and background-repeat to no-repeat to keep just one image centered, but again it just depends on how you want it to look:

```
textarea#contactfooter {
    background-color: rgba(76, 73, 73, 0.44);
    background: url(https://psycheseminars.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/textback.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```